# Closures and Interiors.

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-groups

Let A ⊆ X be a subset of a metric space. Prove the following:

(a) $\overline{A^c}= (\mathring{A})^c$;

(b) $\mathring{A^c}=(\overline{A})^c$.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work please. I advice you to sketch the set $A$ and I think you'll have some ideas on how to prove it.

Comment: What is the [Closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $A^c$ ? Apply the def.

Comment: What is the [Interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) of $A$ ? Apply the def.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline{A}$ is the set of elements of $X$ such that any open ball around them intersects $A$, that is, $$\overline{A} = \{ x \in X \mid \forall \epsilon > 0, B(x,\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset \}.$$  Similarly, one definition of interior is the set of elements of $X$ such that you can find an $\epsilon$-ball around them contained in $A$, that is,$$\mathring{A} = \{ x \in X \mid \exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t. } B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A \}.$$

Now, to prove the first claim, first we will show $\overline{A^{c}} \subseteq (\mathring{A})^{c}:$

> Let $x \in \overline{A^{c}}$.  Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B(x, \epsilon) \cap A^{c} \neq \emptyset$.  But this means any ball around $x$ will intersect with $A^{c}$, which means you can never find a ball around $x$ that is contained in $A$.  That means $x \not \in \mathring{A}$.  Thus, $x \not \in \mathring{A} \implies x \in (\mathring{A})^{c}$.

Now to show $(\mathring{A})^{c} \subseteq \overline{A^{c}}:$

> Let $x \in (\mathring{A})^{c}$.  Then $x \not \in \mathring{A}$.  But this means there does not exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A$.  But this means for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B(x,\epsilon) \cap A^{c} \neq \emptyset$, and this is precisely what we need for $x \in \overline{A^{c}}$.  So we are done.

Can you do the second claim now?

Comment: I am still unsure how to prove the second claim?

Comment: Try and show your work and where you get stuck

Comment: I have got. For Int(A^c)⊆(Cl(A))^c. Let x∈Int(A^c) for some ε>0, B(x, ε)⊆A, which implies x∉cl(A) which implies x∈(Cl(A))^c.

Comment: And then for (Cl(A))^c⊆Int(A^c) . Let x∈(Cl(A))^c which implies x∉Cl(A). Thats as far as I have gotten so far.